# What is inside of the 200 star chest?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare-2

In the sewers down near all of the gnome items, there is a chest that costs 200 stars. I have 83 right now, and I'm wondering if I should keep saving them, or just spend them now? If I knew what was inside maybe it'd be worth it. Does someone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [Everlasting Crown](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Everlasting_Crown), and it speaks to you occasionally.

Comment: So I'm thinking I won't buy it for that much unless I *really* wanna flex.